# iPhone Build Error (Entitlements)

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

I'm getting this error when trying to build:
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016).

This is not my first time building apps. This will be my sixth app, so this thing is tripping. I'm making an AppStore distribution build, so I dont need entitlements. I dont have any entitlement files specified in my code signing entitlement. ITS BLANK. For the project info pane and the target info pane, there is absolutely nothing in my code signing entitlements, which is how its supposed to be. Yet I still get this dumb error. Remember, this is NOT an adhoc build, rather it is an AppStore build. What can be the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple versions of Xcode installed (such as one of the betas)? Did you change the install directory after installing your current stable version of Xcode? Xcode installs things for code signing that can break if you either install a new version of Xcode simultaneously, or you rename your /Developer directory.

Also, try checking the console for related error messages.

Comment: I installed a new verison of Xcode the other day, but I only started building this app today, so its fresh..

Comment: What would happen if I just submitted this build even though it doesnt run on my iPhone. It runs on simulator fine

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Xcode installed? Did you install it in the default /Developer and leave it there?

Comment: I dont think so..how do I make sure?

Comment: Plus it works fine when I use non-distribution profiles, like developer profiles..

Comment: In the root of your HDD, do you have a single Xcode folder named "Developer"? Or do you have a number of folders there (possibly include "Xcode 4")?

Comment: Also, did you actually check the Console?

Comment: I checked the console. Everything was good to go. It said the build was succesful. It just doesnt run on my iPhone. It runs on simulator. Is that enough for me to upload it to Apple? And I only have one Xcode installed

Comment: Ok this has to be an Xcode issue. All my other apps that I had saved before are now giving me the same error

Comment: Not the Xcode Debugger Console, your System Console. Open Console.app and see if you see any warnings/errors (particularly those mentioning 'codesign') when you try to build for distribution.